# How to using regexp_contains for the similiar first word

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

i have a data with entrance_page_name:

```
/search?q=
/search?
/search?ast
```

can i get the data with the similar first word

```
WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(entrance_page_name, '^/search/q=') THEN 'search?q='
WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(entrance_page_name, '^search?') THEN 'search?'
```

But it's not really works. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: What is the input and required output?

Comment: the input I have a data of the user with the first word is /search....... and there are many types of search. I want to group this type of search from a similar first character.  So, I can separate how many types of search with /search?q= and with /search? (without q=...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can possibly use the raw string, and an escape character to override ? symbol.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS('/search?q=SDbmoLZK89s', r'^/search\?q=') THEN 'search?q=' END as test
```

The above code should ideally work in your situation.